# Value of state variable different inside useEffect hook (firestore onSnapshot callback)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, use-effect

I am running into an issue where a state value (`loadMore`) inside a firestore's `onSnapshot`'s callback is different to what it is when entering the hook, and I'm unable to understand why. Perhaps some smarter soul out there will be able to spot the problem:

```ts
   useEffect(() => {
     console.log("loadMore", loadMore); // returns false
     if (cursor) {
      onSnapshot(
        query(
          firestore
            .collectionGroup("posts")
            .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
            .startAfter(cursor)
            .limit(POSTS_PER_REQUEST_LIMIT)
        ),
        (querySnapshot) => {
          console.log("loadMore", loadMore); // returns true
        }
      );
    }
    }, [cursor, loadMore]);
```

As you can see, the problem is that, as expected, `loadMore === false` when the useEffect hook is fired but the `onSnapshot`'s callback function still believes it is `true`. Why? I will keep searching for answers but, in the meantime, will be questioning my own sanity. Thanks to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `onSnapshot`'s success listener has stale values. This can be because it's an outdated listener which needs to be unsubscribed from when one of the dependencies changes.

Firestore's [`onSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#web-version-9) returns a function that you can use to unsubscribe / clean up outdated callbacks.

You can return that function in `useEffect` and it should fix your issue:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (cursor) {
   const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
     query(
       firestore
         .collectionGroup("posts")
         .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
         .startAfter(cursor)
         .limit(POSTS_PER_REQUEST_LIMIT)
     ),
     (querySnapshot) => {
       console.log("loadMore", loadMore); // should be correct now
     }
   );
   return unsubscribe;
 }
}, [cursor, loadMore]);
```

You can read more about effect cleanup in the React documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup

Comment: Dear Jean, you're absolutely correct! I was assuming that, upon each render, the listener callback would simply have the freshest values for whatever the useEffect hook's dependency array contains. Apparently I was wrong. The listener requires a cleanup before it can be attached again, thus using the new values provided to the hook. Thanks again, you're a life saver!